# How to extract the value from the string in BigQuery

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, bigdata

I have the following value as String in one column in bigquery table. I need to extract the content value using BigQuery view.

```
{type:System.Int32,content:202104}
```

I have converted the string like below and tried the JSON_EXTRACT syntax its working.

```
SELECT 
JSON_EXTRACT(JSON'{"type":"System.Int32","content":202104}', '$.content') 
AS json_data;
```

But I have converted this manually from

```
{type:System.Int32,content:202104}
```

to

```
{"type":"System.Int32","content":202104}
```

How can I achieve the same using query? Can anyone help me to resolve this query, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `REGEXP_EXTRACT` to directly extract the value of the "content". Please refer to [BigQuery REGEXP_EXTRACT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_extract) for more information on the usage of this string function.

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT('{type:System.Int32,content:202104}', r'content:(\d+)') as CONTENT_EXTRACT
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This may help:

```sql
SELECT 
JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(REGEXP_REPLACE('{type:System.Int32,content:202104}', r'[^\:\,{}]+', r'"\0"'), '$.content')
AS json_data
```